# Interpretation on the Log-Lin model with high coefficients

Tags: regression, logarithm

So my model has some high coefficients and i have many doubts how should I interpret them

$LnHomii_t = 1.183 - 0.535 LnRendai_t + 4.46\times 10^6Escolai_t - 7.98\times 10^7BOLFAMi_t - 5.378Ginii_t + 0.665LnPIBi_t + ui_t$

This is the end result of my model made through stata. My School (School), Gini and GDP coefficients are in their linear form, while the dependent variable is in its logarithmic form. My question is about the interpretation between the cited variables and the dependent variable. According Gujarati (Pg 190. 2011) the interpretation should be, for example, B2 * (100) or School B1 * (100). However, the coefficients of the mentioned variables are above 1 and because of that the interpretation would present high values, for example 4.46 * 100 = change over LnHomi . Is this kind of interpretation correct or not, or is there a right way to do it?

Comment: Is your model linear regression with a logged outcome variable? Resale variables like $Escolai$ and $BOLFAMI$ appropriately. You can multiply the variables by 100000 and your coefficients will not be as large.

Comment: thanks for tip
but in the books i find 100*(b1) and not 10000. Im asking this because the coefficients seems to be very high multiplying by 100 or 10000.

Comment: You didn't reply the question about whether this was OLS. Also, you need to @ me for me to notice your reply. There is nothing special about multiplying by 100 unless there is some specific rationale for it. You can multiply/divide by any number to make the scale of coefficients easy to work with. I suggested 100k, try 1M, ... All you have to note is that your predictor is the original multiplied by 100k or whatever you choose to multiply it by.

Comment: oh @HeteroskedasticJim, Sorry, im new here. So my model its a regression with panel data, i run OLS, Fixed and Random, plus all tests.

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim, even if my coefficients gets very high, like 100000*(-5,378) or 100000*(4,46), there's no problem interpreting the very high coefficients?

Comment: the best thing to do will be to edit this information into the question. Provide as much information as possible for the reader to understand the model. Naming software packages and commands may also help clarify what you've done.

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim. Done. By the way, thanks for the tip

Comment: Please clarify the sense in which these coefficients are "very high."  In general, the magnitude of a regression coefficient is completely without meaning until you disclose the values of the corresponding variable. For instance, a human height of one billion might seem "very high" until you learn the units are nanometers.

Comment: @whuber By very high i mean above 1, for exemplo, 100*(0,01B1) = 1% and the other is multiply 100*(1B1) = 100%. But i understood what you say. In my model I estimated the impact of each of these variables exposed here on the LnHomi (Number of Homicides, used as a proxy for crime). So, would it be correct to interpret that a variation of 1 unit in School provides a variation of 100 * (4.46) = 446% in crime, that is, the number of homicide can increase by 446%?

Comment: If "school" is the same as "escolai," then your question says increasing the value of this variable by $1$ is expected to increase the log of the response by $4.46\times 10^6\times 1.$ That is the same as multiplying the response by $\exp(4.46\times 10^6),$ which is an astronomical number.

Comment: @whuber That's why I'm losing my nerves.